# Display and save contents of a data frame with multi-dimensional array elements

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have created and updated a pandas dataframe to fill details of a section of an image and its corresponding features.

```
slice_sq_dim = 200
df_slice = pd.DataFrame({'Sample': str,
               'Slice_ID':int,
               'Slice_Array': [np.zeros((slice_sq_dim,slice_sq_dim))],
               'Interface_Array': [np.zeros((slice_sq_dim,slice_sq_dim))],
               'Slice_Array_Threshold': [np.zeros((slice_sq_dim,slice_sq_dim))]})
```

I added individual elements of this dataframe by updating the value of each cell through row by row iteration. Once I have completed my dataframe (with around 200 rows), I cannot seem to display more than the first row of its contents. I assume that this is due to the inclusion of multi-dimensional numpy arrays (image slices) as a component. I have also exported this data into a JSON file so that it can act as an input file during the next run. The following code shows how I exactly tried this and also how I fill my dataframe.

```
Slices_data_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Slices_dataframe.json")
if os.path.isfile(Slices_data_file): 
    print("Using the saved data of slices from previous run..")
    df_slice = pd.read_json(Slices_data_file, orient='records') 

else:
    print("No previously saved slice data found..")
    no_of_slices = 20
    for index, row in df_files.iterrows():                  # df_files is the previous dataframe with image path details
        path = row['image_path']
        slices, slices_thresh, slices_interface = slice_image(path, slice_sq_dim, no_of_slices)
        # each of the output is a list of 20 image slices 

        for n, arr in enumerate(slices):
           indx = (indx_row - 1 ) * no_of_slices + n
           df_slice.Sample[indx] = path
           df_slice.Slice_ID[indx] = n+1
           df_slice.Slice_Array[indx] = arr
           df_slice.Interface_Array[indx] = slices_interface[n]
           df_slice.Slice_Array_Threshold[indx] = slices_thresh[n] 

    df_slice.to_json(Slices_data_file, orient='records')
```

I would like to do the following things:

- Complete the dataframe with the possibility to add further columns of scalar values
- View the dataframe normally with multiple rows and iterate using functions such as df_slice.iterrows() which is currently not supported
- Save and reuse the database so as to avoid the repeated and time-consuming operations

Any advice or better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After some while of searching, I found some topics that helped. `pd.Series` was very appropriate here. Also, I think that there was a "SettingwithCopyWarning" thatI chose to ignore somewhere in between. Final code is given below:

```
Slices_data_file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Slices_dataframe.json")

if os.path.isfile(Slices_data_file): 
    print("Using the saved data of slices from previous run..)")
    df_slice = pd.read_json(Slices_data_file, orient = 'columns')            

else:
    print("No previously saved slice data found..")

    Sample_col = []
    Slice_ID_col = []
    Slice_Array_col = []
    Interface_Array_col = []
    Slice_Array_Threshold_col = []
    no_of_slices = 20
    slice_sq_dim = 200

    df_slice = pd.DataFrame({'Sample': str,
               'Slice_ID':int,
               'Slice_Array': [],
               'Interface_Array': [],
               'Slice_Array_Threshold': []})

    for index, row in df_files.iterrows():
        path = row['image_path']
        slices, slices_thresh, slices_interface = slice_image(path, slice_sq_dim, no_of_slices)

        for n, arr in enumerate(slices):
            Sample_col.append(Image_Unique_ID)
            Slice_ID_col.append(n+1)
            Slice_Array_col.append(arr)
            Interface_Array_col.append(slices_interface[n])
            Slice_Array_Threshold_col.append(slices_thresh[n])

        print("Sicing -> ", Image_Unique_ID, " Complete")

df_slice['Sample'] = pd.Series(Sample_col)
df_slice['Slice_ID'] = pd.Series(Slice_ID_col)
df_slice['Slice_Array'] = pd.Series(Slice_Array_col)
df_slice['Interface_Array'] = pd.Series(Interface_Array_col)
df_slice['Slice_Array_Threshold'] = pd.Series(Slice_Array_Threshold_col)

df_slice.to_json(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "Slices_dataframe.json"), orient='columns')
```